# problem with checkbox item insertion in database table

Tags: database, checkbox

While i am inserting the checkbox selected list item to the database table i am getting this error "Error converting data type nvarchar to bit" In the table i have a field called Disease with bit datatype. My motto to store the different type of disease in one field. Here is selecting checkbox item code: Pls somebody point me out where is my error or give some new idea how can i do the same in better way....

```
string typeofdisease = "";
foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxListDisease.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        typeofdisease += li.Value;
    }
}
typeofdisease = typeofdisease.TrimEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the framework or database you are using, but I'll bet that li.value is always a string containing "Yes" or "No".  As a result, you are trying to shove a string into a boolean field.  You need to convert your "Yes" and "No" to 1 and 0 respectively.  Or, you need to change your database column from boolean to char.

Comment: Hi I am using SQLServer 2000, VS2005

Comment: If it's an asp.net program, then the buttons are certainly containing a "Yes"/"No" value.  I ran into the same problem some time ago.